# How to create file on SFTP server in Cypress test

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, ssh2-sftp

When I call the `createFile()` function in my Cypress test, I am trying to create a file on a hosted SFTP server.

Currently, when I call it, I get the following error message:

The following error was thrown by a plugin. We stopped running your tests because a plugin crashed. Please check your plugins file (`C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\cypress\plugins\index.js`)

> Error: put: Internal server error.
> sftp://myHost.com@sftp.next.rec-test.com:2022/reports/
> at fmtError (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\src\utils.js:55:18)
> at WriteStream. (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\src\index.js:728:18)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
> at WriteStream.emit (events.js:323:22)
> at Object.cb (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\SFTP.js:3629:12)
> at 101 (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\SFTP.js:2622:11)
> at SFTP.push (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\SFTP.js:278:11)
> at CHANNEL_DATA (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:525:23)
> at 94 (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\handlers.misc.js:859:16)
> at Protocol.onPayload (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:2025:10)
> at AESGCMDecipherNative.decrypt (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\crypto.js:987:26)
> at Protocol.parsePacket [as _parse] (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:1994:25)
> at Protocol.parse (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:293:16)
> at Socket. (C:\Dev\SFTP_POC\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:713:21)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
> at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
> at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)

Below is my current `index.js` code:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    createFile() {
      const fs = require('fs');
      let data = fs.createReadStream('C:/Dev/SFTP_POC/cypress/fixtures/example.json');
      let remote = 'sftp://myHost.com:2022/reports/'; 
      let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
      let sftp = new Client();
      const config = {
        host: 'myHost.com',
        port: '2022',
        username: 'myUsername',
        password: 'myPassword'
      };

      sftp.connect(config).then(() => {
        sftp.put(data, remote);        
      })
        .then(data => {
          console.log('Success');
        })
        .then(() => {
          sftp.end();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
      return null;
    }
  })
}
```

My `remote` variable is a folder that exists on the server.
However, after the test, a new file isn't being added.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, & how to resolve it